# Developing a Facebook canvas app locally - (MAMP, Codeigniter)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-canvas

I am starting my first Facebook app, hosted on Heroku. I have set up an app on Heroku for production and a separate app running locally on my own machine for development. Currently, the app (which has very little functionality) runs on localhost just fine. But I don't understand if the app should be able to run like a typical canvas app on the localhost with Facebook functionality. For example, will the Requests Dialog run in a canvas app locally. Should I be able to use that functionality locally as I develop? If so, what steps do I need to take to get that working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't understand if the app should be able to run like a typical canvas app on the localhost with Facebook functionality

Your app should behave the same way whether it is on localhost or on the final production server.

Facebook dialogs (requests, messages..) should display on your local (dev) machine as they  do on the live server. In my case to make this work I setup a secondary "facebook app" with different values for `App Domains`, `Site URL` and `Canvas URL`.

This allows you to run your app from localhost. If you app is canvas-only it will run inside an iframe (which points to `Site URL`) but will be displayed within Facebook.

Also, make sure you're including [Facebook's JS API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) if you want to see any of the Facebook modal boxes rather than pop-up windows.

The only difference you should notice is that if you share a page from your localhost dev site via the FB API, Facebook won't be able to crawl your site and get any icon, image or description should it need to.

Comment: @jordy are you still having problems with this? hope I was able to clarify things a bit!

Answer (score 4):

**The differences**
The only real difference between a standalone site and a canvas app (or page tab) you'll see is that you won't have a `signed_request` passed in when you load your page.

App dialog will still work, but in popup instead of directly on the page. Plus, you'll be able to login user like you would if you set your local dev URL (eg `http://localhost:5000`) in the Facebook app settings under "*Website with Facebook Login*" (or mobile web).

There's also some stuff you won't be able to test on the server like realtime update where facebook send a request to your site to notify an update.

There may be some other things, but this is what I can think about right now.

**Working locally**
So, what I usually do, is develop it locally. To manage the **missing `signed_request`**, I only provide a stub one or I just don't count on it being present so my app can run out of facebook too.

For **login methods**, I tend to rely only on the JS SDK as most of server side login through a canvas app will rely on the `signed_request` - and enaway, I found the UX login better via the JS SDK.

Then, I only setup two FB app, one staging and one for release. The staging app point to my locals urls so my Facebook will allow connection from it.

At this point, it should mostly work fine out of the box!